# Remote video forwarding using VLC through putty

Tags: ssh, video, putty, vlc-media-player, xming

I'm having some problems forwarding video output using putty in a windows machine. I see it like this:

[image]

and here: https://superuser.com/a/985789/508625 they told me it was because my vlc was using the Color ASCII video output. I tried other outputs but vlc couldn't play them.

A couple of colleagues are connecting to the server using ubuntu and mac ssh commands in the console and they can see the video perfectly fine; so I think the problem is on my Windows configuration.

I'm using the latest versions of PuTTy and Xming: 0.65 and 6.9.0.31 respectively. The Putty X11 forwarding is enabled and the display uses the value returned by the $DISPLAY variable in the server. The Xming is also running. And when I test a graphic application in the command line (i.e xyes, gedit, vlc) it runs correctly. (if I close the xming, the apps don't open). Finally, I'm using Windows 10, but I've also tested it on Windows 8 with the same results.

Could it have something to do with some weird Xming configuration? What other ways are there to forward video remotely in Windows? (the server is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server, so there is no native graphic environment)

Comment: Are you running VLC from the remote service via Xming?  If so, why not just use a local copy of VLC on Windows?  I'm guessing the problem is that VLC can't open a suitable video output driver since is going over a remote connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remote video forwarding works well on unix using ssh command, but not in windows using putty and x11](http://superuser.com/questions/985818/remote-video-forwarding-works-well-on-unix-using-ssh-command-but-not-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can test with an other client ssh. There is bitvise ssh Client it's similar to Putty and include a SFTP client, a remote client and X11 fowarding too, it works fine.

Here is where you can find it: https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download

Comment: Where can I find that?

Comment: https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download